# Not able to load properties file in Dynamic web project in Eclipse for Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I've put the properties file in Webcontent folder of my dynamic web project. But, it throws null pointer exception. Here is my code.

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("Resources.properties");
    System.out.println(input);
    Properties properties = new Properties();       
    properties.load(input);     
    System.out.println("MySQL Driver :"+properties.getProperty("mysqlDriver"));
```

### My properties file include

```
mysqlDriver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I'm getting error at InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("Resources.properties");

The error is

```
Feb 09, 2016 2:58:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DatabaseAccess] in context with path  [/iNTU] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the "Resources.properties" file in the "src" folder of your dynamic web project (create it by right-clicking Jara Resources/src > new > general > File, named "MyResources.properties").
The code to read the properties file should then be updated to:

```
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/Resources.properties");
//If you use a subfolder of src, please update accordingly.
```

With that, Eclipse will know how to deploy the compiled files to the war's WEB-INF/classes along with the properties file.

Comment: Ernest, I don't have src or src/main/resources path. I've Java Resources:src, in which I can add only packages, folders or classes.

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Put the file in the folder where your java source packages are.

Comment: But how can I put the properties file there? You mean along with the classes?

Comment: What is the layout of your project? Do you have sevlets or other Java source files? How are you compiling? If you have a non-java file in your sources folder, it will be copied over by the compiler to the destination directory. But your build system can affect this. If you're using an eclipse dynamic web project, put the file under "src" (assuming that's your java source directory). If you're using maven to build, put the Resources.properties file in src/main/resources. If you're using ant, then put the file in the top-level src folder.

Comment: I'm using Dynamic web project in Eclipse. In src, I can add only a wizard. Properties file, I can't

Comment: Right-click "src" under your project tree, Select New, then 'Other'. Under 'general', select "File". In the file name, type "MyResources.properties". When the file opens, add the 'mysqlDriver' property with its value then save. Eclipse will know how to export the file to the 'WEB-INF/classes' folder.

Comment: I've tried that too.. It asks the parent folder, I tried the under project itself & I tried under web-inf/lib too.. But still not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102978/discussion-between-ernest-kiwele-and-syed).